# Php function zip folder no works

Tags: php, zip

I use one function I see here for zip folders , and works nice but I see great problem when I use this kind of slash `../`

**The function :**

```
<?php
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true) {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if (in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1), array('.', '..')))
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true) {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            } else if (is_file($file) === true) {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    } else if (is_file($source) === true) {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
?>
```

In my case i need zip folders out of where file with function for zipping works

When i use this function with this slash , the result it´s inside zip there are nothing , it´s empty

If i try use this code with folders in the same level , and no need use "../" all works fine

**Actually my problem it´s when use the function in this way :**

```
<?php
    Zip("../images","backup_images.zip")
?>
```

**But if i use as here , works right**

```
<?php
    Zip("images","backup_images.zip")
?>
```

Comment: so is there an `images` folder one level above wherever you're running this code?

Comment: No the file for create backup it´s inside one folder called admin_backup and folder of images it´s outside of where i have the admin for backups , by this i need use "../" , regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you substitute the absolute path instead?

`Zip("../images","backup_images.zip")`

becomes:

`Zip("/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/full/path/to/images","backup_images.zip")`

You can use `phpinfo();` within a PHP file in the same place as backup_images.zip to find the correct directory.

Comment: I need use with slash , no paths , regards

Comment: @Francisco `../` is a path

Comment: Yes right as you want you can tell relative or absolute path in this case relative , regards